# Wrapping text inside a CSS shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, css-shapes

I would like to justify/wrap my text inside a triangle to follow its border shape.
I've made an example using a parallelogram, but the result isn't satisfying.

```
.parallelogram { 
    width: 200px; 
    padding: 20px; 
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); 
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg); 
    transform: skew(-30deg);
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 80px;
}

.parallelogram .text {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg); 
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg); 
    transform: skew(30deg);
    margin: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HarrysNature/noqa6qLc/3/

Any idea?

Comment: Hello, 
Here is a good article https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/ but you'll see that it's not well supported yet

Comment: look at this : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

Answer (score 12):

You can align the text to an oblique line by using [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) in combination with [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

[image: preview]

### How it works

- create a new element `<div class="shape"></div>` before your text
- create a thin parallelogram shape out of it with

  ```
  shape-outside: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
  ```
- Let it `float: left` to make the text align to the right border of the shape
- adjust its `height` and `width` according to the angle of your `transform: skew()`

**The good**: Due to the `polygon()` method, you can create whatever shape you like and let text float around it. You can even make it responsive by setting relative units to its `width` and `height`.

**The bad**: Won't work in IE/Edge, see browser compatibility on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility).

For demonstration purposes, I added a `background` a `clip-path` to the shape, to see how it actually works. Of course you can remove those 3 rules:

```css
.shape {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
  /* the following three lines are only for demonstration purposes */
  background: #444;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0, 10% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.parallelogram {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.parallelogram .text {
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallelogram">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="shape"></div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split text on line and wrap each to div:

```
.parallelogram { 
width: 230px; 
padding: 20px; 
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); 
-moz-transform: skew(-30deg); 
transform: skew(-30deg);
background: #ccc;
margin: 80px;}

.parallelogram .text {
width: 220px;
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg); 
-moz-transform: skew(30deg); 
transform: skew(30deg);}


<div class="parallelogram">
<div class="text">
    text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="text">
    text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="text">
    text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="text">
    text text text text text text text text
</div>
```